# Push and pull is not working properly

Tags: html, push, pull

I am trying to make a responsive page using bootstrap 3. The problem is that in small screen devices the text is superposed one another. I am using col-sm-push-2 to arrange the text in sm devices but it affects md devices too. Below is my code. I appreciate every opinion. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="title" content="FTI - Fakulteti i Teknologjise se Informacionit" >
    <meta name="Author" content="FTI" >
    <meta name="description" content="Fakulteti i Teknologjise se 
        Informacionit synon, sigurimin e cilësisë dhe plotësimin e standarteve 
        akademike, për të fituar akreditimin e brendshëm dhe të jashtëm për të 
        gjitha programet e studimit të ciklit të parë, të ciklit të dytë dhe te 
        ciklit te trete që ofrohen nga FTI" >
    <meta name="keywords" content="Fakulteti i Teknologjise se 
        Informacionit, FTI , standarteve akademike, akreditimin ebrendshëm, 
        ciklit të parë, të ciklit të dytë, ciklit te trete, Albania,FTImedia" >
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fti">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21938677-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
<ul>
    <li style="background-color:#aa0000; color:#fdfefe; border-color: #870000; list-style-type:none"><a href="pages/48" title="Departamenti i Elektronikës dhe Telekomunikacionit">
            Dekani dhe Zv.Dekani</a></li></br>

    <li style="background-color:#aa0000; color:#fdfefe; border-color: #870000; list-style-type:none"><a href="pages/44" title="Departamenti i Inxhinierisë Informatike">
            Organet Drejtuese</a></li></br>

    <li style="background-color:#aa0000; color:#fdfefe; border-color: #870000; list-style-type:none"><a href="pages/125" target="_qkzh" title="Departamenti i Bazave të Informatikës">
            Administrata</a></li></br>

    <li style="background-color:#aa0000; color:#fdfefe; border-color: #870000; list-style-type:none"><a href="pages/124" title="Gjendja e Studentit">
            Departamentet</a></li></br>

    <li style="background-color:#aa0000; color:#fdfefe; border-color: #870000; list-style-type:none"><a href="pages/115"><blink>Misioni i FTI</blink></a></li></br>




</ul> 
</div>


<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
<h1>DEKANI DHE ZV.DEKANI</h1>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:medium;">Program për zhvillimin e Fakultetit të Teknologjisë së Informacionit, për periudhën 2012-2016.</span></strong></p>
<p><strong> </strong></p>
<p><strong>Objektivat kryesore</strong></p>
<p><strong> </strong></p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>1.  </strong><strong>Sigurimi i cilësisë dhe plotësimi i standarteve akademike,</strong> për të fituar akreditimin e brendshëm dhe të jashtëm për të gjitha programet e studimit të ciklit të parë, të ciklit të dytë dhe të ciklit të tretë që ofrohen nga FTI.</p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>2.  </strong><strong>Mbështetje për zhvillimin dhe fuqizimin në të tri njësitë e </strong><strong>Fakultetit të Teknologjisë së Informacionit:</strong></p>
<p>-  Departamenti i Inxhinierisë Informatike;</p>
<p>-  Departamenti i Elektronikës dhe Telekomunikacionit;</p>
<p>-  Departamenti i Bazave të Informatikës.</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>3.  </strong><strong>Kualifikimi i stafit të ri në shkollën e doktoratës TIK</strong></p>
<p>-  Lektorët me titull Master i Shkencave në FTI, të regjistruar në ciklin e tretë, në vitin 2009, të ndiqen me përparësi nga Këshilli i Profesorëve të FTI, në mënyrë që të përfundojnë brenda vitit 2013 punimin e doktoratës, në përputhje me kuadrin ligjor në fuqi.</p>
<p>- Lektorët me titull Master i Shkencave në FTI, të regjistruar në ciklin e tretë, në vitin 2010, të ndiqen me përparësi nga Këshilli i Profesorëve të FTI, në mënyrë që të përfundojnë brenda vitit 2014 punimin e doktoratës, në përputhje me kuadrin ligjor në fuqi.</p>
<p>-  Fuqizimi i laboratorëve në shkollën e Doktoratës me anë të aplikimit në projekte, konkretisht projekte të infrastrukturës laboratorike për ICT.</p>
<p>- Laboratori i Arkitekturave, Sistemeve Operative dhe Rrjetave;</p>
<p>- Laboratori i Inxhinierisë së Softuerit, kompilatorëve dhe Gjuhëve të Programimit;</p>
<p>- Laboratori i Sistemeve të Telekomunikacioneve dhe Protokolleve të Rrjetave;</p>
<p>- Laboratori i Përpunimit të Sinjaleve dhe Aplikimeve Multimediale.</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>4.  </strong><strong>Pjesëmarrje në konferenca dhe workshope</strong>, duke mbështetur financiarisht pjesëmarrjen e stafit për të mundësuar kualifikimin e mëtejshëm shkencor.</p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>5.  </strong><strong>Mbështetje për përsosjen e mësimdhënies në programet e studimit Bachelor dhe Master:</strong></p>
<p>-  Qëllimi parësor përgatitja e të diplomuarve në Masterat Shkencorë, të ofruar nga FTI, në mënyrë të tillë që të diplomuarit mund të kryejnë punë kërkimore të kualifikuar; duke zhvilluar më tej progresin shkencor dhe teknologjik; si dhe për të krijuar një klasë udhëheqëse me nivel të lartë profesional.</p>
<p>-  Puna studimore dhe projektuese në Master do të synojë që studentët e FTI në mënyrë individuale të pasurojnë njohuritë kërkimore shkencore gjatë përgatitjes së tezës së diplomës, duke thelluar gjithnjë e më shumë përgatitjen teoriko-shkencore dhe sidomos atë praktike në drejtimet më bashkëkohore të teknologjive të informacionit.</p>
<p>-  Të krijohen kushte për hapjen e programit të studimit në Master Profesional në Shtator 2012, në bashkëpunim me universitete jashtë vendit. Për këtë ndihmesë të madhe do të japë bashkëpunimi i ngushtë me kolegët shqiptarë nga universitetet më në zë në Evropë dhe më gjerë, dhe me profesorë të tjerë të huaj të ftuar në FTI.</p>
<p>-  Bashkëpunimi me institucione të tjera, për të përftuar eksperiencë në laboratore kërkimore me emër në fushën përkatëse. Kjo duke shfrytëzuar lidhjet e vendosura jashtë vendit, kryesisht me universitetet ku kemi stafin e ftuar, si Gjermania, Franca, Spanja, Italia, Japonia, SHBA etj. Do të kërkohet mbështetje financiare me projekte të përbashkëta me universitetet e BE-së, në kuadër të FP7; të bashkëpunimit me DAAD, si dhe mundësi të tjera për të vizituar laboratoret më me eksperiencë jashtë vendit, në kuadër të fondit të ekselencës, të projekteve të kërkim  zhvillimit të MASH etj.</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>6.  </strong><strong>Mbështetje për përmirësimin e kushteve në mjediset e FTI-së</strong>, sidomos për studentët, por edhe për punonjësit akademikë dhe të tjerë.</p>
<p>Qëllimi parësor do të jetë përmirësimi i kushteve në këto mjedise për të zhvilluar leksionet me mjete bashkëkohore teknologjike dhe me nivel të lartë profesional. Përpjekje për zgjerim hapësirash brenda FTI-së, salla leksionesh, laboratore dhe mjedise të tjera për studentët dhe stafin, duke kërkuar mbështetje nga instancat përkatëse.</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>7.  </strong><strong>Përpjekje për aftësimin praktik të studentëve në të dy ciklet e studimit </strong>jo vetëm në mjediset brenda FTI-së, por edhe jashtë, në lidhje të ngushtë me kompanitë celulare, ISP, bizneset private që ofrojnë mundësi bashkëpunimi.</p>
<p>-  Bashkëpunim për zhvillimin e praktikës në mënyrë sa më cilësore dhe me përftim të ndërsjelltë për studentët.</p>
<p>-  Bashkëpunim të ngushtë për zhvillim punime tezash dhe udhëheqjen e tyre, për mbështetje në procesin mësimor, për projekte kërkimore të përbashkëta, por edhe për mbështetje në përmirësimin e kushteve të mësimdhënies në FTI.</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>8.  </strong><strong>Përmirësim dhe kërkesë për rritjen e  cilësisë së punës në administratën e FTI-së</strong></p>
<p>-   Përsosje e informatizimit të Sekretarisë Mësimore dhe Degës së Financës, të nisur tashmë gjatë periudhës së mëparshme, informatizim i gjithë proceseve dhe veprimtarive përkatëse të tyre.</p>
<p> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>9.  </strong><strong>Pasurim i Bibliotekës me tituj librash, revistash, ose dhe me regjistrim on-line në internet</strong>, për të zgjeruar më tej informacionin për studentët dhe stafin, duke u përpjekur për të qenë gjithmonë në përditësim me arritjet e reja në fushat e teknologjisë së informacionit.</p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"> </p>
<p style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>10.  </strong><strong>Përpjekje për informim të shpejtë, të gjerë dhe të saktë për studentët,  dhe për të gjithë të interesuarit e tjerë.</strong></p>
<p>-  Përmirësim i kushteve dhe rritje e kërkesës në FTI për informimin e studentëve gjatë procesit mësimor, për sqarimin e tyre dhe të interesuarve të tjerë në kohë dhe cilësinë e duhur. Kjo në lidhje me orarin mësimor, ecurinë e regjistrimit, të zhvillimit të provimeve, të praktikave, mbrojtjes së diplomave etj. , për arritjet në veprimtarinë botuese, mësimore, kërkimore që zhvillohen nga njësitë përbërëse të FTI-së etj.</p>
<p>-  Përmirësim i cilësisë dhe pasurim i vazhdueshëm i faqes së internetit të FTI.</p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:medium;">Dekani</span></strong></p>
<p class="bodytext"><strong>Prof. Asoc. Vladi Koliçi<br /></strong></p>
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
<p class="bodytext">Universiteti Politeknik i Tiranës<br /> Fakulteti i Teknologjisë së Informacionit</p>
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
<p class="bodytext">Sheshi Nënë Tereza 1, Tiranë<br /> Telefon: +355.42.278159</p>
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
<p class="bodytext"><a href="mailto:vkolici@fti.edu.al"><span style="text-decoration:underline;">vkolici@fti.edu.al</span></a></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:medium;"> </span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="font-size:medium;">Zv. Dekani</span></strong></p>
<p class="bodytext"><strong>Prof. Asoc. Olimpjon Shurdi<br /></strong></p>
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
<p class="bodytext">Universiteti Politeknik i Tiranës<br /> Fakulteti i Teknologjisë së Informacionit</p>
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
<p class="bodytext">Sheshi Nënë Tereza 1, Tiranë<br /> Telefon: +355.42.278159</p>
<p class="bodytext"> </p>
<p><a href="mailto:oshurdi@fti.edu.al"><span style="text-decoration:underline;">oshurdi@fti.edu.al</span></a></p>       
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where to use Push and pull classes on your code

Comment: Any responsive Bootstrap class **will affect all resolutions upwards from the defined one**. This is called *mobile first* approach. If you want different behaviour for md, you need to provide col-md classes as well. Please make sure you understand the basic underlying concepts before using a framework like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the "col-sm-push-2" behaviour on md screens, use "col-md-push-0" to reset the push-2, set in sm screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using `push` and `pull` in `boostrap` like below.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```